# ¿Como agregar objetos desde php a un archivo json?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, phpmyadmin

Tengo varios objetos obtenidos de mysql, logré generar un .json con todos ellos, el problema es que para obtenerlo debo ir a la ruta del archivo de php en el navegador y este me generará el json en el mismo directorio en el que se encuentra. Entonces si quiero agregar otro objeto en la base de datos tendré que eliminar el json y generar uno actualizado. Mi idea es que esto último no sea necesario, sino que cualquier cambio en la bd se refleje en el json

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$bd = "slcw";
$usuario = "usuarioEva3";
$pass = "evaluacion3";


$connect = @mysqli_connect($server,$usuario,$pass,$bd);

$query = "SELECT * FROM epp;";

$resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

$json_array = array();

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
   $json_array[] = $registro;
}

$encoded_data = json_encode($json_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('epp.json',$encoded_data);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Paula, si tenes acceso al script que agrega un registro a la DB, como acto seguido, podrías actualizar el archivo JSON.

Comment: La respuesta general es "no se puede", pues podrías agregar datos a la tabla desde phpMyAdmin, SQLWorkBench, un programa de escritorio o la propia consola del servidor. Como ha dicho Marcos antes, si tienes un script que añade registros y quieres desde ese script _actualizar_ el archivo, si que es posible, pero haría falta incluir esa información en la pregunta para poder responderla en esa línea.

Comment: Ah, y Bienvenida a StackOIverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour].

Comment: ¿Usas el [tipo Json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?

Comment: Y porque no generas el archivo en caliente? Es decir, no por cada registro de bd actualizas el archivo json, sino mas bien generas el archivo json con todos los registros cuando alguien pida el json. Asi no importa si hay 20 inserciones en bd, si nadie pide el archivo no generas nada

Comment: @jachguate, no habia considerado el caso de que ingresaran datos desde otro lado. Si fuera factible este escenario, me parece que se podría crear un trigger que ejecutara un SP el cual hiciera el SELEC, lo convirtiera a JSON y finalmente lo escriba en el archivo. Algo así como lo planteado en la respuesta de David.JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, tal y como lo planteas, no es posible.

Y no porque desde MySQL no puedas generar un fichero JSON, que con esta simple consulta podrías:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'nombre_campo1',campo1,
  'nombre_campo2',campo2
  )
  INTO OUTFILE '/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/epp.json'
  FROM tabla;
```

Si no porque, desde MySQL y por seguridad, no es posible reescribir un fichero, ni eliminarlo para crear uno nuevo. Tendrías que ir creando nuevos ficheros con nombres diferentes, como por ejemplo `epp_20230711_0845.json`.

Vas a tener que apoyarte en otro lenguaje, como el PHP que usas, para poder eliminar el fichero y entonces, ya sí, lanzar la consulta para actualizar el fichero.

Lo que no es necesario es que te vayas al navegador, siempre puedes hacerte un programa en Python, por ejemplo, que periódicamente borre el fichero y lance la consulta para crearlo de nuevo.